# empty drop down fields appearing after decoding ajax response to drop down

Tags: javascript, json, forms, drop-down-menu

i am getting a json like this after using an ajax to call a web service,i have decoded the json to alert each value as employee and temporary one after the other,now i would like to bring these values into the drop down field of a form with the id ultra,i am getting 
2 empty fields for the drop down +the va;ues i ahve decoded  .My json response in items is

```
["Employee","Temporary"]
```

my codd for ajax calling and decoding the result and alerting each element in the return json

```
function ajax(){
 var loc=document.getElementById('category_id1').value;
alert(loc);
var req;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
req=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
 else
 {// code for IE6, IE5
 req=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
}
req.open("POST", "ajax.php?&loc="+loc+"", true);
req.send();
var html
req.onreadystatechange=function(){
   if(req.readyState==4&&req.status==200){
       //$(".error").hide();
       result=req.responseText
       //alert(result);
       var items = JSON.parse(result);
       //alert(items.length)
       for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++)
        {
            var item = items[i];
            //alert(item);
            html=html+"<option value="+item+">"+item+"<option>"
        }

       }
       document.getElementById("Ultra").innerHTML=html
   }
 }
<form>
<label for="subcategory">Sub Category</label>
<select style="width:305px" name="subcategory" id="Ultra" onchange="run()"> 
<option value="">Select</option>
</select>
</form>
```

the form field  after on the same page is
i dont get empty field  here what i am doing wrong 
Thank you

Comment: Tag javascript instead of php. Use code Indenting. Instead of alerting, have you tried inserting a '<option value="">name</option>' into your code?

Comment: no i have not inserted option .let my try that

Comment: no luck i got some error

Comment: i have made the modifications in the code can any one say me what i am doing wrong

Comment: You have too many closing brackets at the end of your code. It's worth tidying up the javascript and laying it out properly as it's very hard to read. It will make your life a lot easier in the future.

Comment: i ahve managed to bring the drop down with the valuse but now there are four options for drop down appearing 1,employee2,blank option,3,temporary,4,blank option how can i remove that i have edited the code my code can any one help me.i need to remove thoose blank options how can i do that

Comment: Please update your question and provide data which appears in `items` variable after `JSON.parse(result);`. Seems like I know what's wrong here, but I need your response data.

Comment: the data that is appearing on the item is ["Employee","Temporary"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you made mistake in your template (unclosed tag) & I'll recommend to use quotes to define select value. You're using

```
html=html+"<option value="+item+">"+item+"<option>"
```

instead of

```
html=html+"<option value='"+item+"'>"+item+"</option>"
```

I created simple jsfiddle which demonstrates how it works: http://jsfiddle.net/KPGhY/

Also add the code here for those who intersting:

HTML is the same and JS is:

```
var items = [ "Employee", "Temporary" ];
var html = '<option value="">Select</option>';
for ( var i = 0; i < items.length; i++ ) {
    html += "<option value='" + items[ i ] + "'>" + items[ i ] + "</option>"
}

document.getElementById("Ultra").innerHTML = html;
```